# Noob query regarding xsl:choose statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I am stuck with this rather simple statement. 
I am trying to use the xsl:choose syntax to get the value of a source which is ‘1’ to display as a position in a workplace such as ‘Partner’.  This is the result I am sourcing:

```
<PresTimekeeper1_TkprDate_Title>1</PresTimekeeper1_TkprDate_Title>
```

the choose statement I am using is:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="./Attributes/PresTimekeeper1_TkprDate_Title = '1'">
     <xsl:value-of select="Partner" />
  </xsl:when>   
</xsl:choose>
```

When I run

```
 <xsl:value-of select="./Attributes/PresTimekeeper1_TkprDate_Title" />
```

The output file displays the number 1. So I know I am using the correct source.

How do I define the 1 so the value-of will display up the word 'Partner' rather than the number 1?

I Apologise if I haven't correctly explained myself.

Comment: Please show us the complete XML. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does your `xsl:choose` have other options beside the single `xsl:when` shown? If not, you'd be better off using `xsl:if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most idiomatic way of writing this would be

```
<xsl:if test="./Attributes/PresTimekeeper1_TkprDate_Title = '1'"
   >Partner</xsl:if>
```

Some people prefer to put the literal string within an `xsl:text` element.

I personally like the idiom:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'Partner'
    [current()/Attributes/PresTimekeeper1_TkprDate_Title = '1']"/>
```

But I don't see many people using it.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Partner" />
```

is looking for a child node named `Partner`. If you want the literal text "Partner", you must use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="'Partner'" />
```

or, preferably:

```
<xsl:text>Partner</xsl:text>
```

---

You can also place the text directly within the `xsl:when` instruction (with no extra whitespace):

```
<xsl:when test="./Attributes/PresTimekeeper1_TkprDate_Title = '1'">Partner</xsl:when>
```